# "errMessage": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'keyword')"

Tags: mern

i'am a begginer in MERN , i am trying to work in backend with MERN, i want create query give me search product in my database Mongose, i work with Postman.

1  i create class in file apiFeaters.js:

```
class APIFeatures {
    constructor(query, queryStr){
        query = this.query;
        queryStr = this.queryStr;
    }

    search() {
        const keyword = this.queryStr.keyword ? {
            name: {
                $regex: this.queryStr.keyword,
                $options: 'i'
            }

        } : {}

        console.log(keyword);

        this.query = this.query.find({ ...keyword });
        return this;
    }
}


module.exports = APIFeatures
```

2  i import this class and i add this in file productController.js

const APIFeatures = require('../utils/apiFeatures');

//Get all products => /api/v1/products!keyword = apple
exports.getProducts = catchAsyncErrors (async (req, res, next) =>{

```
const apiFeatures = new APIFeatures(Product.find(), req.query)
                              .search()
const products = await apiFeatures.query;
```

/*  const products = await Product.find(); */

```
res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    count: products.length,
    products
    
    
})
```

})

Comment: Your queryStr is undefined for some reason! Try using the '?.' (optional chaining)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: thank it work , i am wrong in contrector :    constructor(query, queryStr){
        this.query = query;
        this.queryStr = queryStr;
    }

Comment: Would you be able to accept that as my answer if I post it?